Find shortest path from multiple source vertex and output the each path length sum against the target vertices
I have written the below AQL shortest path traversal query to find the shortest paths from a set of start vertices to a set of target vertices.
In the output I would like a consolidated result. Meaning, output all the target vertex and the total path length of this vertex from all the sources. If no path were found from source to target then add a default value say 10.
How do I modify my query to solve this?
FOR target IN ["ENTITY_PERSON_ID/d628f984-7ece-3927-97dc-fbc0d8488ffa",
  "ENTITY_PERSON_ID/d478c57b-bb24-3c20-b09d-e2cd04b54a58",
  "ENTITY_PERSON_ID/4dacec6f-c14d-3379-b268-97641d4193e3",
  "ENTITY_PERSON_ID/abbc6fd5-e9fa-375f-b9b3-7eed21e44092"]
FOR start IN ["ENTITY_PERSON_ID/88507ee7-d52e-311f-9394-726fa4886819","ENTITY_PERSON_MAILING_ADDRESS_CITY/5b75a553-11ab-3c1f-a7bd-5afc2cb72fdd"]
LET path = (FOR v, e IN ANY SHORTEST_PATH start TO target GRAPH GrpahName RETURN [v, e]) 
SORT LENGTH(path)
RETURN {
vertex_id: target,
path_len: LENGTH(path)
}


If you only interested to find out if the path has been found or not, you can use this approach, return 1 and check if the LENGTH is bigger than 0.
LET path = (
    FOR v, e IN ANY SHORTEST_PATH start TO target GRAPH 'GraphName'
      RETURN 1
)
RETURN {        
    pathLength: LENGTH(path) > 0 ? LENGTH(path) : 10,
}

